# Subtract object in front of other objects to make it transparent on intersection

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

**I am new to blender** and tried searching for 2 days now how to solve this but I am unable to formulate my question properly to find an answer that was probably answered somewhere. I am aware that it needs compositing or a certain node setup but I am still afraid of those.

My situation is that I am making a virtual tour for a client and the room is rendered as a equirectangular image.

There is one base layer of the whole room with sofa, table, carpet etc. and the end product is to be completed in 3dVista to make it interactive so the walls, floor and couch change color.

Every color change has a transparent rendered image that should go over the original room, and that's no issue for the sofa that is not covered by anything from the camera angle.

But when it comes to walls and floor they are covered by many objects and in the place of those objects covering the floor for example should be a transparent silhouette of that object so it can be overlapped with a PNGA.

I hope I explained it I will leave a picture of the whole room and successful sofa layer.

<sup>Full Room</sup>
[image: full room]

<sup>transparent layer to be added on top</sup>
[image: transparent layer to be added on top]

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for your fast and accurate response!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project ;)